# How do you initialize an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

How do you initialize an array in C#?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Like this:

```
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

or this:

```
int[] values = new int[3];
values[0] = 1;
values[1] = 2;
values[2] = 3;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking the second method is not called initialization. Thought that the reader was interested in initializers.

Comment: Well, in the second method, the 1st line does do initialization with default values.

Answer (score 18):

```
var array = new[] { item1, item2 }; // C# 3.0 and above.
```

Answer (score 9):

Read this:
[Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

```
//can be any length
int[] example1 = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
            
//must have length of two
int[] example2 = new int[2]{1, 2};           

//multi-dimensional variable length
int[,] example3 = new int[,]{ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

//multi-dimensional fixed length
int[,] example4 = new int[1,2] { { 1, 2} };

//array of array (jagged)
int[][] example5 = new int[5][];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char[] charArray = new char[10];
```

If you're using C# 3.0 or above and you're initializing values in the decleration, you can omit the type (*because it's inferred*)

```
var charArray2 = new [] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int [ ] newArray = new int [ ] { 1 , 2 , 3 } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
```